# Daily LocalNotification with Start & End Time

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I want a `notification` to repeat daily, but with the start time, end time & frequency(fixed) given.

Say, start time is 10am, endTime 6pm & frequency is every 3hrs, then it should trigger notification at 10am, 1pm, 4pm respectively.

**Note**:- the application has 3 other local `notification` (with different title & body), so need to differentiate the notifications as user can stop any of these notifications anytime.

Tried with `DLLocalNotification` but it didn't solve my problem.

```
DLNotificationScheduler().repeatsFromToDate (identifier: String, alertTitle: String, alertBody: String, fromDate: Date, toDate: Date, interval: Double, repeats: RepeatingInterval, category: String = " ", sound: String = " ")
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For posting the local notification with repeat, you can use below code :

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Pizza Time!!"
        content.body = "Monday is Pizza Day"
        content.categoryIdentifier = "pizza.reminder.category"

        //Date component trigger
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        //example for Gregorian calendar. Every Monday at 11:30AM
        dateComponents.hour = 11
        dateComponents.minute = 30
        dateComponents.weekday = 2
        // for testing, notification at the top of the minute.
        dateComponents.second = 0

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
            dateMatching: dateComponents,
            repeats: true)


        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "pizza.reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error in pizza reminder: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

You can add multiple types of notification by defining the different identifiers for each.

To Stop the local notification,

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["pizza.reminder"])
```

To get the notification of the local notifications which are still remaining to be posted, you can use below code

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {
            (requests) in
            displayString += "count:\(requests.count)\t"
            for request in requests{
                displayString += request.identifier + "\t"
            }
            print(displayString)
        }
```

This things are sufficient enough to add some logic and meet your requirements.
For more information you can follow :

https://makeapppie.com/2017/01/31/how-to-repeat-local-notifications/

Comment: It might repeat daily, but i need to repeat it 3-4 times a day till the user turns off the notification (ie., 10AM, 1PM, 4PM, 7PM today, tomorrow... ) - this is for 1 notification, similarly the app has 2 similar notifications (Notification2 might trigger at 9AM, 12PM, 3PM, 6PM today, tomorrow... Notification3- 4PM, 10PM today, tomorrow...) for this i can use different identifiers, but how to repeat them daily between these time intervals? Again user can't change the frequency, he could change the start & end time for each notifications or turn off.